# Python/Twisted lag between sending and receiving data on localhost

Tags: python, twisted

Long time StackOverflow lurker here, first time asking.

TLDR: When sending a packet from client script to server script using socket.sent (and a twisted reactor) packets seem to be taking anywhere between 30 seconds and 2 minutes to be received on the server script. Connection/disconnection requests are instantaneous.

I'm currently working on a project for university, a python metric monitoring tool for servers.

Most of the code is more or less done, I wont include it all as there's a lot however I'll do my best to provide everything that should be needed to answer my question.

So, the client calls the following when run

```
    core.init()
    core.import_dir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "plugins"))
    factory = client.NSTClientFactory()
    security_form = "with certificate verification" if core.config.client.tls_verify else "without certificate verification"
    logging.info(f"Connecting reactor to port {core.config.client.address}:{core.config.client.port} {security_form}.")
    reactor.connectSSL(core.config.client.address, core.config.client.port, factory,
                       ssl.CertificateOptions(verify=core.config.client.tls_verify))
    logging.info("Running the reactor.")
    reactor.run()
```

`core.init()` contains the following:

```
def init():
    global client
    client = None
    global threads
    threads = []
    global ex_dir
    ex_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __file__ ))
    # Modules Database, key => action, value => function
    global actions
    actions = {}
    # initialises core.config
    global config
    config = configman.init()
    # loads token from file for reestablish
    global uid
    uid = None
    global token
    token = load_token()
    global hname
    hname = socket.gethostname()
    global ostype
    ostype = platform.system()
```

So, once the `init()` is run the reactor instantiates as NSTClient (the code for which is below)

```
class NSTClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = NSTClient

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        logging.error(f"Connection failed {reason.getErrorMessage()}")
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        logging.error(f"Connection lost: {reason.getErrorMessage()}")
        reactor.stop()
```

and also this code

```
class NSTClient(LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        core.client = self
        if core.config.client.token == None:
            # creates the same UUID every time
            r_id = str(uuid.uuid1(uuid.getnode()))
            # generate the token
            token = core.gen_token(r_id)
            core.config.client.token = token
            core.update_config(core.config.client)
            # sends it to the server
            total_storage, free, used = core.actions["get_disk_metrics"]()
            core.socket_send(self, json.dumps({
                "action":"register",
                "uuid":r_id,
                "token":token,
                "hostname":core.hname,
                "OS":core.ostype,
                "Total_Storage":total_storage
            }))
        else:
            r_id = uuid.uuid1(uuid.getnode())
            core.socket_send(self, json.dumps({
                "action":"reestablish",
                "hostname":core.hname,
                "uuid":core.uid,
                "token":core.token
            }))
        for thread in core.threads:
            thread.start()
            logging.info(f"Started thread \"{thread.name}\".")
```

From here data can be sent pretty easily using the function `core.socket_sent(client, data)` where `client` refers to the NSTClient object (`core.client = self`)

This works just fine for the most part. However I've noticed that the messages seem to become more and more delayed as time goes on. Here's an example of a script sending data this way.

```
            elif core.ostype =="Darwin":
            while True:
                packet = {
                    "action": "listen_ports",
                    "port_data": []
                }
                logging.debug("[i] Checking mac os ports")
                port = "22"
                ports_regex = "(\w*[\W\d]\w*)\s*(\d*)\s*(\w*)\s*(\w*)\s*(\w\w\w[4])\s(\w*)\s*(\w*)\s*(\w*)\s([*-.\w]*):(\d*)\s([(LISTEN)]*)"
                data = subprocess.check_output(['lsof', '-i', '-P']).decode('utf-8')
                for line in data.splitlines():
                    matched_ports = re.search(ports_regex, line)
                    if matched_ports is not None:
                        logging.debug("[+] Port data gathered" + str(matched_ports))
                        packet["port_data"].append({
                            "protocol": matched_ports.group(8),
                            "bound_addresses": matched_ports.group(9),
                            "port": matched_ports.group(10),
                            "pid": matched_ports.group(2),
                            "application": matched_ports.group(1),
                            "user": matched_ports.group(3),
                            "IPversion": matched_ports.group(5)
                        })
                logging.debug("Sending packet")
                core.socket_send(core.client, json.dumps(packet))
                sleep(60)
```

I didn't include the whole script as it's long, but you can see it calls `core.socket_send(core.client, json.dumps(packet))`. This in turn sends the packet to the server and it is received every time without error.  The issue, however, is that the first time I run this it takes around 30 seconds from being sent to being received, not that bad, it's useable.

The second time however it'll take closer to a minute, and the third time just over a minute. It doesn't seem to get much worse than that.

However, the script its self runs every 60 seconds, as you can imagine I end up being at least 1 message delayed.

Is this just normal when sending a large packet of data this way?

Here's a copy of the packet for anyone interested:

```
"{'action': 'listen_ports', 'port_data': [{'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': '*', 'port': '49173', 'pid': '425', 'application': 'rapportd ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '49452', 'pid': '521', 'application': 'P72E3GC48 ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': '*', 'port': '17500', 'pid': '557', 'application': 'Dropbox ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '17600', 'pid': '557', 'application': 'Dropbox ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '17603', 'pid': '557', 'application': 'Dropbox ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': '*', 'port': '57621', 'pid': '601', 'application': 'Spotify ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': '*', 'port': '49254', 'pid': '601', 'application': 'Spotify ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '15292', 'pid': '687', 'application': 'Adobe\\x20', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '45623', 'pid': '720', 'application': 'node ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '49477', 'pid': '720', 'application': 'node ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '49478', 'pid': '720', 'application': 'node ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '56423', 'pid': '720', 'application': 'node ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '11456', 'pid': '759', 'application': 'DashlaneP ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '6942', 'pid': '887', 'application': 'pycharm ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '63342', 'pid': '887', 'application': 'pycharm ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}]}"
```

from "127.0.0.1:52306".

When that packet is sent the client outputs:

```
[2020-07-30 15:36:46 - DEBUG] [core.py:103 - socket_send() - Listen Port Scanner] [i] Sent UTF8 encoded packet.
```

and on receipt the server outputs:

```
[2020-07-30 15:36:42 - DEBUG] [serverfactory.py:11 - deserialise() - SerMon MK2] [i] Received "{'action': 'listen_ports', 'port_data': [{'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': '*', 'port': '49173', 'pid': '425', 'application': 'rapportd ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '49452', 'pid': '521', 'application': 'P72E3GC48 ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': '*', 'port': '17500', 'pid': '557', 'application': 'Dropbox ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '17600', 'pid': '557', 'application': 'Dropbox ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '17603', 'pid': '557', 'application': 'Dropbox ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': '*', 'port': '57621', 'pid': '601', 'application': 'Spotify ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': '*', 'port': '49254', 'pid': '601', 'application': 'Spotify ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '15292', 'pid': '687', 'application': 'Adobe\\x20', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '45623', 'pid': '720', 'application': 'node ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '49477', 'pid': '720', 'application': 'node ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '49478', 'pid': '720', 'application': 'node ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '56423', 'pid': '720', 'application': 'node ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '11456', 'pid': '759', 'application': 'DashlaneP ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '6942', 'pid': '887', 'application': 'pycharm ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}, {'protocol': 'TCP', 'bound_addresses': 'localhost', 'port': '63342', 'pid': '887', 'application': 'pycharm ', 'user': 'chrisblakey', 'IPversion': 'IPv4'}]}" from "127.0.0.1:52306".
[2020-07-30 15:36:42 - DEBUG] [core.py:99 - get_action() - SerMon MK2] [i] Valid action "listen_ports" provided, corresponds to the action "ports".
[2020-07-30 15:36:42 - DEBUG] [core.py:215 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] 15 port data objects received.
[2020-07-30 15:36:43 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 15 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:43 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking rapportd.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:44 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:44 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on rapportd 
[2020-07-30 15:36:44 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:44 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking P72E3GC48.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:45 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:45 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on P72E3GC48 
[2020-07-30 15:36:46 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:46 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking Dropbox.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:47 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:47 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on Dropbox 
[2020-07-30 15:36:47 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:47 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking Dropbox.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:48 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:48 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on Dropbox 
[2020-07-30 15:36:49 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:49 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking Dropbox.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:50 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:50 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on Dropbox 
[2020-07-30 15:36:50 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:50 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking Spotify.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:51 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:51 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on Spotify 
[2020-07-30 15:36:52 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:52 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking Spotify.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:52 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:52 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on Spotify 
[2020-07-30 15:36:53 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:53 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking Adobe\x20.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:54 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:54 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on Adobe\x20
[2020-07-30 15:36:55 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:55 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking node.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:55 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:55 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on node 
[2020-07-30 15:36:56 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:56 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking node.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:57 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:57 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on node 
[2020-07-30 15:36:58 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:58 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking node.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:36:58 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:36:58 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on node 
[2020-07-30 15:36:59 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:36:59 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking node.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:37:00 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:37:00 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on node 
[2020-07-30 15:37:01 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:37:01 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking DashlaneP.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:37:01 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:37:01 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on DashlaneP 
[2020-07-30 15:37:02 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:37:02 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking pycharm.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:37:03 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:37:03 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on pycharm 
[2020-07-30 15:37:04 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:37:04 - DEBUG] [core.py:222 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Checking pycharm.Enabled against Listening_Ports table.
[2020-07-30 15:37:04 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:81 - get_data() - SerMon MK2] [i] Fetched data from sermondb: [(0,)]
[2020-07-30 15:37:04 - DEBUG] [core.py:235 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Setting Enabled to True on pycharm 
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [dbinterface.py:65 - send_data() - SerMon MK2] 1 rows affected.
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:243 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] [i] Open ports:
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -rapportd  listening on *:49173
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -P72E3GC48  listening on localhost:49452
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -Dropbox  listening on *:17500
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -Dropbox  listening on localhost:17600
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -Dropbox  listening on localhost:17603
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -Spotify  listening on *:57621
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -Spotify  listening on *:49254
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -Adobe\x20 listening on localhost:15292
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -node  listening on localhost:45623
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -node  listening on localhost:49477
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -node  listening on localhost:49478
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -node  listening on localhost:56423
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -DashlaneP  listening on localhost:11456
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -pycharm  listening on localhost:6942
[2020-07-30 15:37:05 - DEBUG] [core.py:245 - port_data_received() - SerMon MK2] -pycharm  listening on localhost:63342
```

As you can see from the output, the server is clearly outputting a previous message (as it receives it about 4 seconds before the client sent it, the client sends this message every 60 meaning that the message must be at least 56 seconds delayed, possibly even longer.

Comment: try using https://github.com/dbader/schedule instead of sleep() to schedule sends, see if it makes a difference - I have a theory but to confirm you must remove that sleep() from the loop

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is going to be difficult to answer in a specific, helpful way.  You've shared a lot of code (maybe more than necessary) but you also haven't shared *enough* code for it to be easy to make sense of.  For example, it's unclear what `core.socket_send` is or does.  Including a complete, self-contained, minimal example is a better way to get useful answers.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask goes into more detail.

Comment: For what it's worth, as written, I think the answer to the question is "You're misusing threads somehow." but I can't quite see how (since the code is incomplete).